# 'o' and last vowel in user input are not found

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

My program is suppose to check one word per line for vowels; however It does not count the the   vowel if it is the last letter in the word or if the vowel is 'o' I have been staring at this for hours. Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vowel
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String word;      
   int len;          
   int position;     
   int vowelCount;   
   char ch;         

   Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);   

   word = kbd.next();          

   while (!word.equals("the_end"))  
   {
     len = word.length() - 1;
     vowelCount = 0;


     for (position = 0; position < len-1; position++) 
     {
       ch = word.charAt(position); 
       if ((ch == 'a') || (ch == 'e') || (ch == 'i') 
       || (ch == 'o') || (ch == 'u')) vowelCount++;

     }

     System.out.print("There ");
     if (vowelCount == 1) System.out.print ("is 1 vowel in ");
     else System.out.print("are " + vowelCount + " vowels in ");

     System.out.println(word);

     word = kbd.next();  
    }
  }
 }
```

I'm now trying with

```
for (position = 0; position < word.length(); position++)
```

Comment: It looks to me like your code won't count the last *two* letters of the word if they're vowels.  So maybe the problem with `o` is that you've only been giving it words like "labor".

Comment: I tried your exact program, after the edits (and before they were backed out): `There are 2 vowels in bone`.  That's the correct answer, right?

Comment: Don't edit your question like that. It makes answers obsolete. If you need to, edit and append any new attempts you don't understand.

Comment: Yea when I type bone I get "there are 0 vowels in bone"

Comment: Not with that code you don't.

Comment: I have even copied the code directly, recompiled and still nothing I dont get it!!!

Comment: Are you typing in "bone" or "BONE"?

Comment: bone, my case only has to handle lower case. Im telling you this code is not working copy and paste it. I am so confused why it is not working!!!

Comment: I have saved and recompiled multiple times, is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Delete your compiled files and then recompile to make sure you're not still running the broken version.

Comment: @ajb is there anyway you could post your edits, I can not figure this out. I have tried everyone's suggestions

Comment: My edits are what I said in my answer: take your original code, and remove two `-1`'s.  The code works perfectly for me.  I have no idea what you might be doing wrong, but it has nothing to do with the Java code.  Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?  If so, perhaps you should start a fresh new project and cut-and-paste in the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (position = 0; position < len-1; position++) 
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

You are stopping your loop before the end of the string.

Also, if you're assigning `len` to `word.length()-1`, you're chopping off a letter that way too. Better just to write:

```
for (position = 0; position < word.length(); position++)
```

I don't know why it would be missing the letter 'o', but you might want to check if you need to convert your string to lower case. Currently, if your vowels are capitals, they won't be counted.

You could do this by putting:

```
word = word.toLowerCase();
```

before your `for` loop.

Comment: This will still be off by 1.

Comment: `len` was created from `word.length() - 1`. It's still a character behind.

Comment: I changed that too, still nothing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm looking at the code in the question, I can't see this `len = word.length() - 1` you refer to.

Comment: @khelwood They've since edited. I edited back to at least show the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a six-letter word, `"kitten"`.  The first character position is 0, so you want `position` in your loop to take on the values, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

What your code actually does:

```
 len = word.length()-1;
```

This sets `len` to 5.

```
 for (position = 0; position < len-1; position++)
```

Since `len-1` is 4, this will only run the loop as long as `position < 4`.  That is, as soon as `position` reaches 4, it exits (since `4 < 4` is `false`).  So `position` will only take on the values 0, 1, 2, 3.  That is, you'll be off by 2.

Getting rid of *both* `-1`s in the above code will eliminate the problem.

Comment: I did that. take for instance the word "bone" it will not count the 'e' because it is the last letter now will it count 'o' for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to iterate over the whole `String`, but you have

```
len = word.length()-1;
...
for (position = 0; position < len-1; position++) 
                           //  ^^^ why?
```

You're making your `String` 2 characters shorter. Don't do that.

```
for (position = 0; position < word.length(); position++)
```

Comment: Still nothing, I get the same results. I think I tried that and changed it back.

Comment: @Jengo Works for me. Do you _think_ you tried it or did you try it?

Comment: I try the word "bone" it wont count my 'o' or the last letter if it is a vowel.

Comment: I did try it, no change.

Comment: @Jengo [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/ALrwMa) You must not be doing the change as I suggested it.